# How to obtain a header value in an apache camel route definition component?

Tags: apache-camel

I have something of the following in my route definition:
`.to(repoConfig.getRepositoryUrl()+"-files?id=" + inject some header value in here)`
and was wondering if it is possible to inject a header value to the end to complete my url string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.to(repoConfig.getRepositoryUrl()+"-files?id=${header.myHeaderName}");`

Comment: You need `toD` for dynamic endpoints, `to` will not work with expressions. Otherwise you are right, but some explanation and link to documentation about dynamic endpoints would make this answer much better.

Comment: @Bedla, in this situation toD is not required as `repoConfig.getRepositoryUrl()` is seemingly simply returning a String. The OP requested only the params to be fetched from the header which does not require `toD`. `toD`would be required if the endpoint would be fetched from the headers too!

Comment: @Bedia Thanks. it was toD that worked. Can you make it an answer so that I can accept?